# How to change Xcode's Build Results view type?

Tags: xcode, ide

Some day ago I've pressed a button in the Build Results window. It was located between the error list and the code subwindow.
Pressing the button changed the view mode from error list to pure compiler output. And the button was gone!

So far I've managed to live with the output, but it's getting really annoying.
How can I switch back to the original "error list" kind of view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In previous versions of Xcode, there were two split views in the build results window: one for the editor and one for the textual build results. If you’re not using Xcode 3.2, try to drag a split view down from the top of the window.

In the current version, there’s only one split view left, which reveals the editor below the graphical build results. The textual results are in expandable bubbles, so I guess that’s not what you’re talking about?

Comment: Thanks! You are right! There was a second split view (three panels in total), but the second was pushed out of the window. Now everything back to original. BTW I'm using Xcode 3.1.4.